# Convert a R column of decimal to the 6th decimal place

Tags: r

Say that I have a R data frame `df`:

```
   id   value
0  a    0.00016
1  b    0.0324789
2  c    0.05583726
3  d    0.02
```

How can I convert `df$value$ into decimals with exactly 6 decimal places like the following?

```
   id   value
0  a    0.000160
1  b    0.032478
2  c    0.005837
3  d    0.020000
```

I tried to use `round(df$value, digits=6)` but it only truncates the ones with the more than 6 decimal places but fails to add more zeros to the ones with less than 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `round()` I use `format()`

```
x <- tribble(~id,   ~value,
 "a",    0.00016,
  "b",    0.0324789,
  "c",    0.05583726,
  "d",    0.02)

x %>% mutate(value_digits=format(value,nsmall = 6))
```

I get the below output:

```
  id      value value_digits
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       
1 a     0.00016 0.000160    
2 b     0.0325  0.032479    
3 c     0.0558  0.055837    
4 d     0.02    0.020000
```

BASE R

```
#assume x to be the name of the dataframe
x$value <- format(x$value,nsmall=6)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way of doing this without needing the dplyr package?

Comment: hi! i only used dplyr::mutate to add a column to show the figures side by side. The key formula here is format() and the nsmall argument.  I'll amend my answer to show you how to do this in base R. if you find this helpful please feel free to select as answer or upvote